# What is Pennywise's intentions and motivations?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, it

In the 1990 miniseries version of IT, we see IT, aka Pennywise, terrorizing and killing a bunch of kids, those of whom survive growing up into adults.

My question is, why?  Why does Pennywise do what it does?  What was it trying to achieve?

---

I am ok with both official sources related to the miniseries and sources from the book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a mysterious evil being from an unknown realm/dimension outside the regions of space. The simple reason it comes to Earth and kill is to feed itself. It preferred to attract children, so it could capture and kill to devour them. It was capable of killing every kind of human but mostly preferred to prey upon innocent human children because they were easier to manipulate and scare. According to the creature, frightened flesh tastes better.

You might read more about the character here: http://stephenking.wikia.com/wiki/It_(creature)